# Ошибка чтения excel файла pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, xlrd

в последней строке выдает ошибку. Попробовал открыть другой файл с методом usecols, отрабатывает все нормально. Пишет ошибка xlrd неизвестный тип файла.

```
bookname = r"C:\Users\Gumin1-AA\2_6 2020-04-01.xlsm"
temp_list_deal_id_bookname = r"\\Braga101\Vol8\RUN_K7M\Python\system\temp_deal_id.xlsx"

temp_list_deal_id = pd.read_excel(temp_list_deal_id_bookname)

portfel = pd.read_excel(bookname,
                        sheet_name = 'FCRED',
                        skiprows=4,
                        usecols = "C:AZ")
```

Comment: можете выложить небольшой XLSM файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник, который помог бы воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: А где в приведенном участке кода обращение к фунциям xlrd???

Comment: @passant, `pd.read_excel` по умолчанию использует `engine="xlrd"`

Comment: @ MaxU - спасибо, никогда не задумывался. Думал, что  xlrd -  для "копырсания" внутри файла, а ввод-вывод файла пандовский  - достаточно примитивная, "внешняя" функция. Буду знать.